# Creating pooled variogram in gstat

Tags: interpolation, kriging, variogram

I am currently using gstat to perform ordinary kriging on daily fields of some variable - that is a new variogram is fit for every daily set of observations.

I would like to compare this with pooling the data over a month (say) and computing a single variogram model from the aggregated data. Note that the locations are fixed in time.

It seems to me that the variogram should be binned only from correlations within a single day, but that aggregating these terms over all days will improve the smoothness (maybe) of the resulting variogram.

My question is how do I achieve this in gstat? I have found this (unanswered) question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202140/kriging-fit-method-and-dx-argument-in-variogram

This mentions using dX=0 but this seems to only ignore contributions between the same spatial locations.

Comment: I added an answer to the question you refer to.

Comment: @EdzerPebesma, because that other question is on a different SE site, perhaps you could post an answer here too; so this question gets answered within GIS. Let me know if you decide to do it. Tks.